# My Dual-boot laptop freezes randomly, what are the possible reasons that we are looking here?

Tags: windows-7, boot, display, freeze, ubuntu-14.04

I have a two year old ASUS X550c which has a dual-boot (windows 7 Ultimate ( Build 7601 Service pack1) and Ubuntu 14.04).

**Specs**:

- Core i5 3rd Generation
- chipset Mobile QM77 Express
- Graphics Intel HD Graphics 4000 (Default)

I had this freezing issue a year back, later it vanished. But now it is back and eating my head. So these are the things I did to find out the root cause:

- Tried booting my Windows 7 in safe boot / safe boot with Networking / safe boot with Command prompt, still it froze after sometime.
- Tried booting Ubuntu and when I playing video from online, it froze again. The video completely stops and if there is any audio output at that time it keeps echoing in a strange way like someone is strangling my laptop.
- Interestingly, many times this happened when I shake the laptop, I mean change its position. Assume when I boot it, it was on my bed and when I place it on my lap, it freezes immediately. However, it freezes even if was not disturbed but happens after sometime.
- Also, I tried checking for System event logs but there is nothing much, actually no error message at all.

After doing all these, I am jumping to the one of the following conclusions from below:

- BIOS issue
- Hardware issue
- Some spell of black magic [this can be possibly ruled out anytime]

Now please, can anybody here tell me what can be the cause of this other than the issues mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest BIOS update and install it: https://www.asus.com/in/support/Download/3/516/0/5/iDj76sQprYFuQe5J/30/

Also look at Event-viewer and look through for the errors just before the crash.